# Apostrophe usage for vehicle name

Tags: apostrophe

This is the context:

'The 21h00 draw features two Suzuki Ignis up for grabs.'

I don't know whether it's *Ignis', Ignis's or just Ignis*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I think the plural form of Suzuki Ignis should be Suzuki Ignises going by the basic rule that the plural form of nouns ending in 's' require a suffix of 'es'. Eg. Plural of 'Jones' will be "Joneses" as in "The Joneses will be joining us for dinner tonight."

Comment: Hello, Priyanka. You could predict that this question has been asked and answered before on ELU, given the number of questions there have been. We don't want to keep duplicating material.

Comment: It has not. The other post you're referring to does not have to do with a name brand. This question has not been answered before and I still require an answer.

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen Your question is exactly analogous to *Travis* in the other question.